# For which $p \geq 0$ this series converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $$f(n) = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\sin n}{\log n}\right)}{n^{p + 1}}$$

And I want to find for which $p \geq 0$ this: $$\sum_{n \geq 2}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\sin n}{\log n}\right)}{n^{p + 1}}$$ series converges.

Here's what I got:

For $p \geq 1$ seems like we can just use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) and say that  $$\sum_{n \geq 2}\left|\frac{\sin(\frac{\sin n}{log\ n})}{n^{p + 1}}\right| \leq  \sum_{n \geq 2}\frac{1}{n^{p + 1}}$$ which converges for $p > 0$.

But what can we do in $p = 0$ case? I have no idea how to prove convergence/divergence in this case. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

For $p=0$ the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\sin n}{\log n}\right)}{n^{p+1}}$ converges.

1. $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^N \sin \left(\frac{\sin n}{\log n}\right)$ is bounded for every integer $N$ (prove this easily with the complex sine definition)
2. $\dfrac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$
3. $\left\{\dfrac{1}{n}\right\}$ is monotonic

We can conclude by [Dirichlet's Test for convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) that the series converges.

Comment: Can you explain 1), please? It would be really helpful cuz I tried to prove this and could't get positive results.
Also thank you for you answer!

Comment: @MathIsGood I will include the proof in the question body.

Comment: Excuse me, but what's the proof? Or u still writing it into question body?